# Should Row be used in place of StringForm?

Tags: programming

I've been using *Mathematica* for a long time, so I have a habit of using some of the older functions even when newer, better ones have been added to replace them.

`StringForm` is one such function. I have the habit of using it with `Print` as the *Mathematica* analog of C's `printf` when I need debugging output. Today, when I found myself typing `Print[StringForm[ ...` once again, the thought "why am I not using `Row`?" occurred to me. Indeed, why not?

`Row` has been in *Mathematica* since ver. 6. It looks to me it can do anything that `StringForm` can do and a lot more. However, WRI has not deprecated `StringForm`, so I wonder: should `Row` always be used in place of `StringForm`? Or is there still some use cases where `StringForm` is better?

Comment: I don't know if this constitutes an answer, but I think of `Row` as a more generic function that allows you to form a row of arbitrary items for visual appearances (e.g. strings and images) and `StringForm` as a more low level function that's useful in injecting values into a boilerplate message. In writing debugging messages, I find `StringForm` easier to use because I can read the text in one go, rather than being broken as in `Row`

Comment: I looked back and found an example where I had used `StringForm` to format the output of `Date[]`. But now `Date` is deprecated and we have `DateString`... So it's definitely true that `StringForm` is not nearly as central to formatting as `Row` is.

Comment: `Row` would seem to be preferred if you want to style words or phrases in Italic, Bold, etc., or with varying color or size or font family, for then you can use `Style`.

Comment: `Message` uses `StringForm`, so I think it can't be deprecated.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries. I think this answers my question by identifying a use case where `StringForm` is essential. If you write it up as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: `StringForm["x = ``", Style[1/3, Red]]` yields a `String`, which looks the same as `Row[{"x = ", Style[1/3, Red]}]` but different than `Row[{"x = ", Style[1/3, Red]}] // ToString`.  Sometimes you might want a `String` (to put into string functions, I suppose); sometimes it might suit your style, such as the use rm -rf mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StringForm` is being used by `Message` and therefore difficult to replace. From the documentation of `Message`:

> `Message[mname,`$e_1$, $e_2$ `,...]` is printed as
>   `StringForm[mess,`$e_1$, $e_2$ `,...]` where `mess` is the
>   value of the message `mname`. Entries of the form `` `i` `` in the string `mess`
>   are replaced by the corresponding $e_i$.

You can see that here:

```
Message[NDSolve::ndnco, "XXXXX", "YYYYY" ]
```

> NDSolve::ndnco: The number of constraints (XXXXX) (initial conditions) is not equal to the total differential order of the system plus the number of discrete variables (YYYYY). >>

If we leave away the variable part of the message we get:

```
Message[NDSolve::ndnco]
```

> StringForm::sfr: Item 1 requested in "The number of constraints (`` `1` ``)
>   (initial conditions) is not equal to the total differential order of
>   the system plus the number of discrete variables (`` `2` ``). >>" out of
>   range; 0 items available. >>
>
> StringForm::sfr: Item 2 requested in "The number of constraints (`` `1` ``)
>   (initial conditions) is not equal to the total differential order of
>   the system plus the number of discrete variables (`` `2` ``). >>" out of
>   range; 0 items available. >>
>
> NDSolve::ndnco: The number of constraints (`` `1` ``) (initial conditions)
>   is not equal to the total differential order of the system plus the
>   number of discrete variables (`` `2` ``). >>

Comment: Unless... we deprecate `Message` too and replace it by `Speak`?